Spring Webflux + Spring Security - PreAuthorize not working work (using Kotlin)
Here is my code:
Security Config
@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
internal class WebAuthorizationConfig(
    private val userDetailsManager: ReactiveUserDetailsManager,
    @Qualifier("customPasswordEncoder") private val passwordEncoder: PasswordEncoder
) {

    @Bean
    fun configureSecurity(
        http: ServerHttpSecurity,
        requestValidationFilter: RequestValidationFilter,
    ): SecurityWebFilterChain {
         http
            .csrf { csrf -> csrf.disable() }
            .addFilterBefore(validEndPointFilter, SecurityWebFiltersOrder.HTTP_BASIC)
            .httpBasic { httpBasic ->
                httpBasic.authenticationEntryPoint(customAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            }
            .authorizeExchange { authorize ->
                authorize
                    .anyExchange().hasAuthority("WRITE")
            }
             .authenticationManager(customAuthenticationManager())
             .securityContextRepository(customSecurityContextRepository())

        return http.build()
    }


    @Bean
    fun customAuthenticationManager(): ReactiveAuthenticationManager {
        return CustomAuthenticationManager(userDetailsManager, passwordEncoder)
    }

    @Bean
    fun customAuthenticationEntryPoint(): CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint {
        return CustomAuthenticationEntryPoint()
    }

    @Bean
    fun customSecurityContextRepository(): ServerSecurityContextRepository {
        return CustomSecurityContextRepository()
    }

}

Controller
@RestController
internal class UserController(
    @Autowired
    private val userService: UserServiceImpl,
) {

    @GetMapping("/users/{uid}")
    final suspend fun getUser(
        @PathVariable("uid") uidString: String
    ): ResponseEntity<UserDTO> {
        // validate user ID
        val uid = userService.validateUserId(uidString)
        // get from database inside this co-routine
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUser(uid))
        }
    }
}

Service
@Service
internal class UserGetServiceDelegate(
    @Autowired
    private val userRepo: UserRepositoryImpl,
    private val userDTOEntityMapMapper: UserDTOEntityMapMapperImpl,
    private val userMapKeyRenamer: UserMapKeyRenamerImpl,
) : UserGetService {

    @PreAuthorize("denyAll()")
    final override suspend fun getUser(uid: ObjectId): UserDTO {

        //** SIGNIFICANT DATABASE STEP **//
        // attempt to get user from database
        val userEntity = userRepo.getUser(uid)
            ?: throw ErrorManager.getException("service-user-does-not-exist")

        // return retrieved user
        return userDTOEntityMapMapper.fromEntity(userEntity)
    }
}

Whatever I do, it still grants access to the sevice, and returns the result, despite having, @PreAuthorize("denyAll()"), in the service?
There are loads of posts going back years, complaining about this. Some suggest adding this annotation @EnableReactiveMethodSecurity (already done). Some suggest removing final (but kotlin, if you remove the visibility modifier it is final by default, and when I chose open or sealed, they are grayed out, and my IDE says they are redundant)
None of them help though.
Any ideas?
Thanks in advance
Update - using Open / removing Final:
I tried making the function open, but that still didn't work for me:

Update 2 - using Mono:
I've also tried this, since some posts say a Spring Security upgrade broke support for Kotlin Co-routines. So, I added an extra layer, and added pre-authorise to that, so it worked with a Mono instead. But this also did not work for me:
Service
    final override suspend fun getUser(uid: ObjectId): UserDTO {

        //** SIGNIFICANT DATABASE STEP **//
        // attempt to get user from database
        val userEntity = userRepo.getUser(uid)
                 ?: throw ErrorManager.getException("service-user-does-not-exist")

        // return retrieved user
        return userDTOEntityMapMapper.fromEntity(userEntity)
    }

    @PreAuthorize("denyAll()")
    override fun getUserSecured(uid: ObjectId): Mono<UserDTO> {
        return mono {
            getUser(uid)
        }
    }

Controller
 @GetMapping("/users/{uid}")
    final suspend fun getUser(
        @PathVariable("uid") uidString: String
    ): ResponseEntity<UserDTO> {
        // validate user ID
        val uid = userService.validateUserId(uidString)
        // get from database inside this co-routine
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserSecured(uid).awaitSingleOrNull())
        }
    }

Update 3 - on controller:
This does work!
 @GetMapping("/users/{uid}")
    @PreAuthorize("denyAll()")
    suspend fun getUser(
        @PathVariable("uid") uidString: String
    ): ResponseEntity<UserDTO> {
        // validate user ID
        val uid = userService.validateUserId(uidString)
        // get from database inside this co-routine
        return withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
            ResponseEntity.ok(userService.getUserSecured(uid).awaitSingleOrNull())
        }
    }

My conclusion is that this is looks like a bug...(if, as it says, it is meant to work in any layer of an application, including the service layer)

I took portions of your example and tried it out with minimal security using Spring boot latest WebFlux, Kotlin, and Java 21. So not sure if this will answer your question or not. I found that using final vs not using it for the method annotated with @PreAuthorize was the difference in getting a 200 or 403 back. Not sure why this is the case, but that's what I tried.
So example code I used (put it all in one Kotlin file for brevity):
package com.example.demo

import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication
import org.springframework.boot.runApplication
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration
import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableReactiveMethodSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.reactive.EnableWebFluxSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.ServerHttpSecurity
import org.springframework.security.config.web.server.invoke
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.MapReactiveUserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.ReactiveUserDetailsService
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User
import org.springframework.security.web.server.SecurityWebFilterChain
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono

@SpringBootApplication
class DemoApplication

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<DemoApplication>(*args)
}

@Configuration
@EnableWebFluxSecurity
@EnableReactiveMethodSecurity(useAuthorizationManager = true)
class WebAuthorizationConfig {
    @Bean
    fun userDetailsService(): ReactiveUserDetailsService {
        val userDetails = User.withDefaultPasswordEncoder()
            .username("user")
            .password("user")
            .roles("USER")
            .build()
        return MapReactiveUserDetailsService(userDetails)
    }

    @Bean
    fun springSecurityFilterChain(http: ServerHttpSecurity): SecurityWebFilterChain {
        return http {
            authorizeExchange {
                authorize(anyExchange, authenticated)
            }
            formLogin { }
            httpBasic { }
        }
    }
}

@RestController
class UserController(private val userService: UserService) {
    @GetMapping("/users/{uid}")
    final fun getUser(@PathVariable("uid") uid: String): Mono<String> {
        return userService.getUser(uid)
    }
}

@Service
class UserService {

    @PreAuthorize("denyAll()")
    // Notice no final keyword on this function - get expected 403. But if final keyword added, I get a 200.
    fun getUser(uid: String): Mono<String> {
        return Mono.just("user")
    }
}

Test with
curl -u "user:user" http://localhost:8080/users/1 -v


Thanks for the comprehensive example. That's very strange. I still can't get mine to return 403 Unauthorised. I removed final, but it says here in Kotlin, https://kotlinlang.org/docs/inheritance.html, that classes are final by default. I applied it to a method though, but removing itt seems to have made no difference. very strange

I wonder if it is something to do with the internal modifier on my classes, since my securityConfig, is in a different package to the userClass and userService classes - and that is causing the annotation to not work. (would be surprised, since PreAuthorise is imported from: import org.springframework.security.access.prepost.PreAuthorize) . I'll see if I can replicate your example, by putting the code in one file, and seeing if it works. Otherwise it might be to do with you using a mono pattern, and me using co-routine / suspend method (again I'd be surprised)

I think it has something to do with AOP + Kotlin since I believe the security annotations use AOP. See:

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/springframework/security/authorization/method/AuthorizationManagerBeforeReactiveMethodInterceptor.java
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/12080
Might be versions you are using too. Just making guesses. Good luck! Maybe try setting some debug points in that Interceptor class?


at akang, does the solution still work for you if you implement an interface for your service?

@Sachin yup seems to work same with interface - I pushed up to https://github.com/akang1108/so-78698990

Thank you! Bizzare, it doesn't for me still. It seems to want a Mono. I've raised the issue here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/15367
